# Merging some polygons when creating Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, query, virtual-layer

I have a polygon layer `'lot'` containing an attribute `"lot_number"`. Then, I want to create a Virtual Layer that merges some of the lots while keeping others separated, as the diagram shows below.

Specifically, in the virtual layer, I want to merge the lots with `"lot_number"` 1, 2 and 4 into one polygon, and ones with `"lot_number"` 5 and 6 into another polygon. How could I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out.
First you need to create a new field `merged_ID` in the `lot` layer, giving a unique ID to each group of polygons to be merged. The attribute table would look like this:

[image]

Then type the following query in the virtual layer creation window:

```
select st_union(geometry), l.*
from "lot" as l
group by l."merged_ID"
```

Comment: When working with a single layer there is no need in an alias i.e. `from "lot" as l`, simply `from "lot"`